# UISplitViewController - Use as slideout-style menu

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm struggling a bit with the new UISplitViewController in iOS 8.

I want to achieve a slideout-style menu on iPhone (landscape and portrait) as well as on iPad in portrait orientation and a persistent sidebar on iPad in landscape orientation.

I got a UITableViewController as the master and a UINavigationController with a couple of UIViewControllers as the detail in my SplitViewController.

Is it possible to to get something like this with the new UISplitViewController in iOS 8?
First it would be enough the get the iphone sliding thing to run :D

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UISplitViewController will do just that. Sliding menus and everything.

It works like a dream if you use it exactly by the book. And this requires setup of some UINavigationControllers as part of the magic.

Tutorial is highly recommended for the first time. It's easy to get it messed up quickly otherwise. :)

http://nshipster.com/uisplitviewcontroller/

Answer (score 3):

By default, the UISplitViewController in iOS8 will only act as a slideout-style menu on the iPad (in both portrait and landscape mode) and iPhone 6+ (in landscape mode only).

As to whether or not it is *possible* to get the slideout-style menu working on all iphones via the splitViewController, I don't actually know (I'm still new to iOS development). I suspect that it entails modifying how the splitViewController treats different size classes. If there isn't an easy way to change the splitViewController's behavior, perhaps you could subclass the splitViewController and override the functionality that you do not like.

I have not tried this before, nor do I actually know how the controller determines how it is displayed in different size classes. However, if I were trying to accomplish what you are, then this is what I would be looking up.